# How to insert multiple inputs with same input name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, foreach

Assume that i have table: transactions with 7 columns:id, date, amount, detail, type, purpose, location. I want to be able to input 3 rows once i click on submit button. In my confiq.php there is connection set up in variable $query.

This is the code that I have in my insertmultiple.php (later it will be included in my overview.php in a table as 3 rows).

Problem: I want to insert 3 lines of data from html form into new rows in table. Do yousee where I make mistake? I have a feeling its somewhere where I start condition if.
Thanks to everyone.

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $detail = $_POST['detail'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];

    foreach( $date as $key => $d ) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (date, detail, type)
        VALUES ('$date[$key]', '$detail[$key]', '$type[$key]')";

        if ( $sql === TRUE) {
            mysqli_query ($query,$sql);
        } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $query->error;
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<tr>
    <input type="text" name="date[]" />
    <input type="text" name="detail[]" />
    <input type="text" name="type[]" />
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type="text" name="date[]" />
    <input type="text" name="detail[]" />
    <input type="text" name="type[]" />
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type="text" name="date[]" />
    <input type="text" name="detail[]" />
    <input type="text" name="type[]" />
</tr>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" style="width: 50px">
</form>
```

Comment: a lot of errors in your code... 1) write the unique name every input fields.for example name="date[]" used 3 times.. it's wrong. you should used date1[], date2[] or date3[]

Comment: fixed this error and update code.. i will guide you

Comment: $sql === TRUE will never be true, $sql is a string.

Answer (score -1):

After preparing the mysqli_connect in (**$CONNECTION**):

```
$CONNECTION = mysqli_connect("IP_ADDRESS", "MYSQL_USER", "MYSQL_PASS", "MYSQL_DBNAME");
```

then:

```
foreach( $date as $key => $d ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (date, detail, type)
            VALUES ('$date[$key]', '$detail[$key]', '$type[$key]')";

    if ( !(mysqli_query($CONNECTION, $sql) === TRUE) ) {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($CONNECTION) . "<br>" . $sql->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: OOP os optional while prepared statements are **obligatory**. and it makes your code error prone and insecure

Answer (score -1):

Your test is wrong, $sql will never be true, it is a string. Try this :

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$date = $_POST['date'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

foreach( $date as $key => $d ) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (date, detail, type) VALUES ('$date[$key]', '$detail[$key]', '$type[$key]')";

  if (mysqli_query ($query,$sql) === FALSE) {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $query->error;
  }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<tr>
    <input type="text" name="date[]" />
    <input type="text" name="detail[]" />
    <input type="text" name="type[]" />
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type="text" name="date[]" />
    <input type="text" name="detail[]" />
    <input type="text" name="type[]" />
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type="text" name="date[]" />
    <input type="text" name="detail[]" />
    <input type="text" name="type[]" />
</tr>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" style="width: 50px">
</form>
```

EDIT : I'm assuming config.php defines `$query` var and open the connection. That being said, you should really use PDO and prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

try this code:
note: read the comments

```
<?php 
include('config.php');


//added an if statment to check if the user have pressed submit (<input type="submit"  **name="submit"** id="submit_button" style="width: 50px">)
// this will insure that the query wont start unless data has been sent
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$date = $_POST['date'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

foreach ($date as $key => $d) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (date, detail, type) VALUES ('$date[$key]', '$detail[$key]', '$type[$key]')";

//        if ($sql === TRUE) { //the $sql will not be true it will be the equal to to the string of the query
//            mysqli_query($query, $sql);
//        } else {
//            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $query->error;
//        }

    if (!mysqli_query($query, $sql)) { //tries to perform the query, if it doesnt work prints the error
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $query->error;
    }
}
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<tr>
<input type="text" name="date[]" />
<input type="text" name="detail[]" />
<input type="text" name="type[]" />
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="text" name="date[]" />
<input type="text" name="detail[]" />
<input type="text" name="type[]" />
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="text" name="date[]" />
<input type="text" name="detail[]" />
<input type="text" name="type[]" />
</tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" style="width: 50px">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for being helpful, the answer from OmarTuffaha and @Hossam worked for me. Also I was able to us emor evalues than 3. The answer from and LP154 did not work for me, I do not knwo why. I got error "unknown index". Thanks for the critics, I am learning only from tutorials and code snippets. my problem is I have found many files about sql and php but I do not know learning sequence, therfore I am just trying to find the code snippets which I need and I put the somehow together. I also know that there are 3 different approaches to write code. I ussualy go for the one with mysqli.

Comment: If you have good resources of knowledge with some practical examples I would appreciate it. My problem is also that i find many codes that are old now. Sometimes its enought to re-write comands like mysql_connect to mysqli_connect but mostly it needs better understanding to be able to really repair or to write my own code. Thanks in advance or if it is too much, please ignore. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

> Hi there, good example. I had the same problem and there is a difference between `grant all privileges on  *.* to root@localhost identified by 'password'`  and `grant all privileges on  *.* to root@'%' identified by 'password'`

if you are using root on localhost you might as well just wanna run the `grant all privileges on  *.* to root@localhost identified by 'password'`

For Your HTML and PHP scrip have

```html
<?php
include 'db_config.php';
if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['detail']) && isset($_POST['type'])) {
   
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $detail = $_POST['detail'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($date); $i++) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO transcations (date, detail, type) " .
                " VALUES ('$date[$i]', '$detail[$i]', '$type[$i]')";

        //$conn is the name of your connection string
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (!$results) {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $query->error;
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <form method="post" action="">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="date[]" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="detail[]" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="type[]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>
                        <input type="text" name="date[]" />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="detail[]" />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="type[]" />
                    </td>             
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="date[]" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="detail[]" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="type[]" />
                    </td>



                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" style="width: 50px">
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>



        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```